# нужно взять словать с дополнительного py файла, отредактировать в основном, а затем сохранить изменения в доп файле

Tags: python, discord.py

Есть 2 файла: основной (main.py) и дополнительный под базу данных (users.py)

**users.py:**

```py
test1 = {
   'lvl': 0
}
```

я хочу взять значение из словаря test1 под именем 'lvl', отредактировать его в main.py и сохранить новое значение в users.py. вот, как я пытаюсь это сделать(естественно оно не работает и тупо чистит файл но я не мог обратиться за помощью, не попробовав):
**main.py(отрывок с самой командой и импортом):**

```py
import users

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.send(users.test1['lvl'])
  f = open('users.py','w')
  f.write(test1['lvl'] == 1) #*1
  f.close()
  await ctx.send(users.test1['lvl'])
```

пробовал писать в *1:

```py
f.write(test1['lvl'] = 1)
```

но тогда выдаёт ошибку:

```py
SyntaxError: expressions cannot contain assigment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

если есть вариант сделать подобную базу проще, то посоветуйте плиз

Answer (score 0):

А такой исправленный вариант:

```
f.write("test1 = {'lvl': %s}"%('1'))
```

Comment: я пробовал но выдаёт ошибку :  SyntaxError: expressions cannot contain assigment, perhaps you meant "=="?

Comment: Чуть подправил, можете глянуть, такой вариант?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: нет, всё равно не то, но я понял, что в данном случае будет проще изучить как пользоваться базами данных. Однако, если всё-таки случится озарение, то скидывайте - думаю, другим ваш ответ будет полезен)

Comment: Ну да, тут лучше подключить sqlite)